# custom SetInterval function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make an custom set interval function for my game but everytime i tried, i end up with a infinite loop. I can't use the default javascript's set interval because it can not take the random number. any idea?

Comment: Sadly, we can't guess what your code looks like. Could you please add your implementation?

Comment: Hey i just want to Change the interval of SetInterval while it's running.


setInterval(function(){
                    ig.game.spawnEntity(EntityInjection,me.ranx,50,{} );
                              },Math.floor(Math.random()*1800+200));

Comment: The solution below should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly then make a custom function that calls itself using setTimeout.

```js
var watchUntil = 10;
var start = new Date().getTime();
function watchDog() {
  console.log("watchDog called!");
  
  if(new Date().getTime() - start > (watchUntil * 1000)) {
    console.log("watchDog terminated!");
    return false;
  }
  
  var pause = (Math.random() * 3) * 1000;
  setTimeout(watchDog, pause)
}
watchDog();
```

An alternative method would be to create a watchdog function that ticks at the update rate of your app, and keeps track of the tasks you want to fire in the future.

This method means that you can get away with using a single setInterval, ticking at your minimum desired refresh rate, and simple pile on the tasks:

```js
var Watchdog = (function () {
    /**
     * Creates an instance of Watchdog.
     *
     * @param {number} [interval=1000 / 60]
     */
    function Watchdog(interval) {
        if (interval === void 0) { interval = 1000 / 60; }
        this.interval = interval;
        this.tasks = [];
        this.start();
    }
    /**
     * @param {Watchdog} self
     */
    Watchdog.prototype.tick = function (self) {
        for (var key = 0; key < self.tasks.length; key++) {
            var task = self.tasks[key];
            task.ticks--;
            if (task.ticks <= 0) {
                task.callback();
                self.tasks.splice(key, 1);
                key--;
            }
        }
    };
    /**
     * callback: what to do when this task is ready
     * ticks: how many times the counter shall run over this task before executing it
     * @param {() => any} [callback=function () { }]
     * @param {number} [ticks=0]
     * @returns Watchdog
     */
    Watchdog.prototype.register = function (callback, ticks) {
        if (callback === void 0) { callback = function () { }; }
        if (ticks === void 0) { ticks = 0; }
        this.tasks.push({
            callback: callback,
            ticks: ticks
        });
        return this;
    };
    /**
     * @returns Watchdog
     */
    Watchdog.prototype.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        return this;
    };
    /**
     * @returns Watchdog
     */
    Watchdog.prototype.start = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.stop();
        this.setIntervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
            self.tick(self);
        }, self.interval);
        return this;
    };
    return Watchdog;
}());
//Create a watchdog and add some tests
var w = new Watchdog(1000 / 60)
    .register(function test1() {
    console.log("Test 1 has completed");
}, 100)
    .register(function test2() {
    console.log("Test 2 has completed");
}, 30)
    .register(function test3() {
    console.log("Test 3 has completed");
}, 150);
//Add another test later, that will still be fired before some of the others:
w.register(function test4() {
    console.log("Test 4 has completed");
}, 50).register(function test5() {
    console.log("Test 5 has completed");
});
```

Comment: While this is a solid approach, as per [setTimeout or setInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval) this approach isn't as precise us using `setInterval`.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 No, but it is more elegant than making and killing `setInterval` handles.